# Border collision only works once in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a snake game in python, and I've almost finished, but I'm struggling to solve an issue. In the main class in the collision method, I wrote some code to detect the snake collision with the borders of the screen, and if the statement is true, the snake will return to its original state. However, when I run the program the collision detection only works once. Afterwards, the snake is able to simply move off the screen. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Screen setup
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

cellSize = 20

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 0, 255)

# Grid
def draw_grid():
    # Vertical lines
    for x in range(0, screen_height, cellSize):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x, 0), (x, screen_height))

    # Horizontal lines
    for y in range(0, screen_width, cellSize):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (0, y), (screen_width, y))

# Maze
class MAZE:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect_width = 20
        self.rect_height = 20
        self.rects = []

    def draw_rects(self):
        # Drawing Maze
        pass


# Snake
class SNAKE(MAZE):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.speed = 20
        self.initBody = [[3 * cellSize, 40], [4 * cellSize, 40], [5 * cellSize, 40]]
        self.body = [[3 * cellSize, 40], [4 * cellSize, 40], [5 * cellSize, 40]]
        self.rects = []
        self.move = [0, 0]
        self.grow = False

    def draw_snake(self):
        # Drawing snake body
        for cor in self.body:
            snake_rect = pygame.Rect(cor[0], cor[1], self.width, self.height)
            self.rects.append(snake_rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, snake_rect)

    def move_snake(self):
        # Key bindings
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.move = [0, -1]

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.move = [0, 1]

        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.move = [-1, 0]

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.move = [1, 0]

        if self.move[0] != 0 or self.move[1] != 0:
            # Adding rects to the end of snake body
            new_rect = self.body[-1][:]
            new_rect[0] += self.move[0] * cellSize
            new_rect[1] += self.move[1] * cellSize
            self.body.append(new_rect)
            # Removing rects from tail
            if self.grow == False:
                self.body.pop(0)

        self.grow = False

# Food
class FOOD_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.x = 4 * cellSize
        self.y = 4 * cellSize
        self.food_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    def draw_food_1(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, self.food_rect)


maze = MAZE()
snake = SNAKE()
food_1 = FOOD_1()

class MAIN():
    def __init__(self):
        self.maze = MAZE()
        self.snake = SNAKE()
        self.food_1 = FOOD_1()
    def draw(self):
        self.maze.draw_rects()
        self.snake.draw_snake()
        self.food_1.draw_food_1()
    def move(self):
        self.snake.move_snake()
    def collision(self):
        # Snake and food collision
        for rect in self.snake.rects:
            if rect.colliderect(self.food_1.food_rect):
                self.food_1.x = random.randint(0, 29) * cellSize
                self.food_1.y = random.randint(0, 29) * cellSize
                self.food_1.food_rect.topleft = (self.food_1.x, self.food_1.y)
                self.snake.grow = True
        # Border collisions
        if self.snake.body[-1][0] <= 0:
            self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody
        elif self.snake.body[-1][0] >= 600:
            self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody
        elif self.snake.body[-1][1] <= 0:
            self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody
        elif self.snake.body[-1][1] >= 600:
            self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody

main = MAIN()

# Main loop
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # Drawing on screen
    screen.fill(black)
    main.draw()
    draw_grid()

    # Movement and Collisions
    main.move()
    main.collision()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(10)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody`, you are not making a copy of `initBody`, you are defining `body` as being the *same object* as `initBody`, so when you modify one, the other is modified too...which happens while playing.

So after the first collision, `initBody` is modified at the same time as `body` (as they have become the *same thing*), so when another collision happens, the line `self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody` does nothing.

You need to replace it with `self.snake.body = self.snake.initBody.copy()` so that the original `initBody` remains intact.

Comment: Also, a general remark: whenever you copy-paste a piece of code several times, you should ask yourself "shouldn't I make a method/function for this?". Sometimes the answer may be no, but as you are about to fix 4 identical lines of code, you probably understand why it would have been good to define a `reset_body(self)` method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Better you make a code like this in your loop.

```
if playerx = 0:
   playerx = 0
if playerx = 600:
   playerx = 600:
```

Use same method for also y axis.